using axios to delete user in Laravel through 500 error
I have a separate table for users which has all users included the roles like admin, user and referee. Now I would like to make another table to manage data related to volunteers data only everything looks fine but when try to delete specific volunteer data axios through 500
fe {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

not sure what cause of this error even in laravel.log says something like this:
[2024-07-24 22:05:35] development.ERROR: Class "App\Http\Controllers\File" not found {"userId":11,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class \"App\\Http\\Controllers\\File\" not found at D:\\projectName\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\VolunteersController.php:201)
[stacktrace]
#0 D:\\projectName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\VolunteersController->DeleteVolunteer('23')
#1 D:\\projectName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('DeleteVolunteer', Array)
#2 D:\\projectName\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(259): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\VolunteersController), 'DeleteVolunteer')
...

This is the code i'm using currently
https://codeshare.io/k0bKq3


Open your controller and import the File class correctly. Right now, it's attempting to resolve it from the current directory where the script calling File:: exists, and it cannot find it there, hence the 500 internal server error.

@Ohgodwhy Thanks,  I did not thought of keyword File in the code when i saw log file the first thing i look into it is userId :( so i need to get more knowledge about log files details carefully in future.

Considering that you set everything else in the right way, as @Ohgodwhy suggested you should import your File class.
use Illuminate\Http\File; //Should do just fine


Based on the code in the question, this is the wrong class. It should be Illuminate\Support\Facades\File
